# matplotlib basic question

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please forgive my simple question. I have just started to use Matplotlib and I am having some difficulty.

I can run the following with the interpretor without problems:

```
>>> from pylab import *  
>>> plot([1,2,3])  
>>> show()
```

The above code generates a beautiful graph.

However, if I place the following code inside a file and run it, I get an error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import sys
import os
from pylab import *

plot([1,2,3])
show()
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sbrown/Desktop/new1.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pylab import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 54, in <module>
    import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py",     line 15, in <module>
    import new
  File "/Users/sbrown/Desktop/new.py", line 2, in <module>
    plot([1,2,3])
NameError: name 'plot' is not defined
>>>
```

Any idea what the problem could be? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: It might be a namespace issue.  What happens if you get rid of the `from pylab import *` and use `import pylab` `pylab.plot([1,2,3])`?

Comment: It looks like the error message is not related to the code snippet you've posted: Where does "import new" comes from? Do you have a new.py file on your desktop?

Comment: @ Stephen Terry I tried your suggestion. No luck, it throws the same error. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: @ Zaur Nasibov Correct, the file name is new.py and it is on my Desktop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you have a file on your Desktop that is shadowing the standard Python `new` module:

```
>>> import new
>>> new
<module 'new' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/new.pyc'>
```

Rename or remove `$HOME/Desktop/new.py` and try again.

Comment: this worked! thanks a million samplebias! lesson learned, do not tangle with reserved words!!!!

Comment: No sweat, I think all Python-ers run into this sooner or later, e.g. you start picking generic names for modules, like `string` or `xml` and run into trouble when they conflict.